# How to split a number in two, each of which lie within a range?

Tags: split, integer, sum, range

While attempting a question, I was required to split a number 'n' into 2 parts, each part falling within a given range (inclusive).

There can be more than one solution obviously, only one is required.

Example - `n = 5 and Range = 2 to 4`

```
       Solutions would be (2,3) (3,2)
```

It's easy in the head but unable to derive a quick logic.
Thank you

Language - C++

Comment: What language are you working in? And also your example contradicts the premise - (1,4) and (4,1) do not have *both* parts in the range 2 to 4, so you would actually only expect (2,3), (3,2) ?

Comment: where is 1,4 in the range 2,4? or do i misunderstand what you mean with range? also which prpgramming languege you want to have?

Comment: Oops,typo! thanks, corrected

Comment: Working in c++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each part to fall "within a given range (inclusive)", the solutions for `n = 5 and Range = 2 to 4` would be `(2,3), (3,2)`.

The most trivial solution is like this:

```
for i = range_min to range_max:
    if range_min <= n - i <= range_max:
        print (i, n-i)
```

Update. A deeper analysis:

```
a = range_min
b = range_max

a <= i <= b

a <= n - i <= b
a - n <= -i <= b - n
-a + n >= i >= -b + n
n - b <= i <= n - a

max(a, n-b) <= i <= min(b, n-a)

for i = max(a, n-b) to min(b, n-a):
    print (i, n-i)
```

There is nothing more efficient possible, as anyway you need to loop through all the matching pairs *at least* to print them, and here there is *only* printing.

Update 2. Only one pair (if exists) and in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> // min, max
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, a, b;
    cin >> n >> a >> b;
    int lo = max(a, n-b);
    int hi = min(b, n-a);
    if (lo <= hi) {
        cout << "(" << lo << ", " << n - lo << ")" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "nope" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's nothing more efficient than a loop, I suppose?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry not very familiar with python (if this is that :P). Do these operations exist in c++?

Comment: Also, if I only had to find the first occurrence and stop there (not print other combinations), would this be better?

Comment: That's just a "quick logic", such operations certainly do exist in C++. Didn't notice this part in your question: "There can be more than one solution obviously, only one is required", you can `break` after the `print` (will update the answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

int l,r,s;

cin>>l>>r>>s;    //here l & r are range & s is sum that we want to split

if(2 * r < s){

cout<<0<<endl;

return 0;

}

int start,end;

start = s - l;

if(start > r){

start -= r;

start += l;

}

end = s-start;

int count = abs(end - start) + 1;

cout<<count<<endl;

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified a language to use, so here's a very basic implementation with JavaScript:

```
var n = 5;
for (var i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
  var first = i + 1;
  var second = n-i-1;
  console.log('(' + first + ',' + second + ')' + ' ' + '(' + second + ',' + first + ')' );
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Ah I just saw your edit - my answer is out of date now :P

Comment: Haha ya, was a typo

Answer (score 0):

I suggest *enumeration* instead of splitting:

1. Validate the input: `to >= from`, `value >= 2 * from`, `value <= 2 * to`
2. Start from `value - to` or `from`
3. Return while both parts in `[from..to]` range

Sample C# 6.0 solution

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> Ranges(int value, int from, int to) {
  if (to < from) // empty range
    yield break;
  else if (value < 2 * from || value > 2 * to) // value is too small or too big
    yield break;

  // start either from left border or from minumum possible value within the range
  int start = value - to >= from ? value - to : from;

  // both i and value - i should be in [to..from] range
  for (int i = start; i <= to && value - i >= from; ++i) 
    yield return new Tuple<int, int>(i, value - i); // (i, value - i) pair
}
```

Test:

```
var result = Ranges(5, 2, 4)
  .Select(range => $"({range.Item1},{range.Item2})");

Console.Write(string.Join(" ", result));
```

Outcome:

```
(3,4) (4,3)
```

Comment: Is the complexity of this better than O(from - to) ? This forms a small part of the code. Better to have a simple implementation

Comment: @borb183: it's not *complexity* that matters, but *validation*. E.g. `(6, 8, 9)` as well as `(6, 1, 2)` should return *nothing*; `(6, 1, 3)` should return `(3, 3)` only etc.

Comment: Needed to use in competitive coding, thus efficiency did matter. Otherwise yes, it's good